# How to compare PANDAS Columns in a Dataframes to find all entries appearing in different columns?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe

Full disclosure. I'm fairly new to Python and discovered PANDAS today.

I created a Dataframe from two csv files, one which is the results of a robot scanning barcode IDs and one which is a list of instructions for the robot to execute.

```
import pandas as pd
#import csv file and read the column containing plate IDs scanned by Robot
scancsvdata = pd.read_csv("G:\scan.csv", header=None, sep=';', skiprows=(1),usecols=[6])

#Rename Column to Plates Scanned
scancsvdata.columns = ["IDs Scanned"]
#Remove any Duplicate Plate IDs
scancsvdataunique = scancsvdata.drop_duplicates()

#import the Worklist to be executed CSV file and read the Source Column to find required Plates
worklistdataSrceID = pd.read_csv("G:\TestWorklist.CSV", usecols=["SrceID"])

#Rename SrceID Column to Plates Required
worklistdataSrceID.rename(columns={'SrceID':'IDs required'}, inplace=True)
#remove duplicates from Plates Required
worklistdataSrceIDunique = worklistdataSrceID.drop_duplicates()

#import the Worklist to be executed CSV file and read the Destination Column to find required Plates
worklistdataDestID = pd.read_csv("G:\TestWorklist.CSV", usecols=["DestID"])

#Rename DestID Column to Plates Required
worklistdataDestID.rename(columns={'DestID':'IDs required'}, inplace=True)

#remove duplicates from Plates Required
worklistdataDestIDunique = worklistdataDestID.drop_duplicates()

#Combine into one Dataframe
AllData = pd.concat ([scancsvdataunique, worklistdataSrceIDunique, worklistdataDestIDunique], sort=True)
print (AllData)
```

The resulting Dataframe  lists IDs scanned in Column 1 and IDs required in Column 2.

```
 IDs Scanned  IDs required
0     1024800.0           NaN
1     1024838.0           NaN
2     1024839.0           NaN
3     1024841.0           NaN
4     1024844.0           NaN
5     1024798.0           NaN
6     1024858.0           NaN
7     1024812.0           NaN
8     1024797.0           NaN
9     1024843.0           NaN
10    1024840.0           NaN
11    1024842.0           NaN
12    1024755.0           NaN
13    1024809.0           NaN
14    1024810.0           NaN
15       8656.0           NaN
16       8657.0           NaN
17       8658.0           NaN
0           NaN     1024800.0
33          NaN     1024843.0
0           NaN        8656.0
7           NaN        8657.0
15          NaN        8658.0
```

How would I go about ensuring that all the IDs in the 'IDs Required' Column, appear in the 'IDs Scanned Column'?

Ideally the results of the comparison above would be a generic message like 'All IDs found'.

If different csv files were used and the Dataframe was as follows

```
    IDs Scanned  IDs required
0     1024800.0           NaN
1     1024838.0           NaN
2     1024839.0           NaN
3     1024841.0           NaN
4     1024844.0           NaN
5     1024798.0           NaN
6     1024858.0           NaN
7     1024812.0           NaN
8     1024797.0           NaN
9     1024843.0           NaN
10    1024840.0           NaN
11    1024842.0           NaN
12    1024755.0           NaN
13    1024809.0           NaN
14    1024810.0           NaN
15       8656.0           NaN
16       8657.0           NaN
17       8658.0           NaN
0           NaN     2024800.0
33          NaN     2024843.0
0           NaN        8656.0
7           NaN        8657.0
15          NaN        8658.0
```

Then the result of the comparison would be the list of the missing IDs, 2024800 and 2024843.

Comment: `all([item in df["IDs Scanned"] for item in df["IDs required"].unique()])`

Comment: You can use `.isin`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check True/False if all the items required are in the column;

`all([item in df["IDs Scanned"] for item in df["IDs required"].unique()])`

To get a list of the unique missing items:

`sorted(set(df["IDs required"]) - set(df["IDs Scanned"]))`

Or using pandas syntax to return a DataFrame filtered to rows where `IDs required` are not found in `IDs Scanned`:

`df.loc[~df["IDs required"].isin(df["IDs Scanned"])]`

Comment: These have all been very useful and I'm learning alot but I still have a few issues. The result always returns False, even when it should be true, I assume because of all the Nan values. Is there a way to amended this? I tried turning all the nan values to 0 but that hasn't helped. The list of the unique missing items is perfect, I just need to work out how to get that into a text file without running into a 'argument must be str, not list' error

Comment: If the list of missing items works then you can convert this to true/false using `bool(sorted(set(df["IDs required"]) - set(df["IDs Scanned"])))` - this returns True if the list has items or False if it is empty. To join a list `l` as string use `", ".join(l)`

Answer (score 0):

```
missing_ids = df.loc[~df['IDs required'].isin(df['IDs Scanned']), 'IDs required']
```

Comment: It would help to add at least a short explanation of this code. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers

Comment: This is great. I just need to work out how to write it to a txt file without getting, argument must be str, not list errors.